# Changing selected option in HTML::Form

Tags: html, forms, perl, http

I am working on an automated form submit script. It is logging in to a vendor's website and populating the fields of a form. When trying to submit, the desired result would be a ticket number displayed, which is acknowledging the form is submitted and the request is processed by their helpdesk.

However the form is not submitted correctly (no acknowledgement is displayed) and I suspect that it is caused by one of the inputs which is a SELECT.

Here is the code I use to set this field:

```
$forms[3]->value('ProductList','-2');
```

This has no effect on the the prepared form unfortunately, dumping $forms[3], i see this:

```
 [...]
    bless({
     'onchange' => ' checkKC(document.all.ProductList, \'~0\'); prodExpand();',
     'current' => 1,
     'menu' => [
      {
         'seen' => 1,
         'value' => '~0',
         'name' => '<Please select>'
      },
      {
         'seen' => 1,
         'value' => '-2',
         'name' => 'Product not found.... Search more'
      },
      {
         'value' => '-1',
         'name' => '------------------------------------'
      },
      {
         'value' => 'Product1',
         'name' => 'Product 1 Name'
      }
     ],
     'name' => 'ProductList',
     'id' => 'ProductList',
     'idx' => 1,
     'type' => 'option'
    }, 'HTML::Form::ListInput' ),
 [...]
```

Am I using the right method of $forms[3]? (it was created by HTML::Form->parse($pageresult) btw) Or is there any other method I should try? I can't find any documentation for HTML::Form::ListInput

Thanks for any advice

Comment: `document.all` is for IE 4.x and 5.0. You shouldn't use it on anything modern.

Comment: Thanks, but that has nothing to do with the basic problem, and is coming from the host webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) for form processing that takes more than one step.  That way you can include the login process in your script along with going to the form and of course getting the result.

Or if you need to work with JavaScript, then use [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox).

Comment: Hi @Miller, thanks for the answer. The issue is that the form is utilizing Javascript (which is making a search field visible in case -2 is chosen in the above dropdown, and then transforming to a new dropdown when enough characters were typed) and that's why I'd rather just fill all the possible input fields. I even sniffed what is posted exactly to the target page with LiveHTTPHeaders to find out if there is any post submit added fields. Not sure if WWW::Mechanize can handle Javascript.

Comment: Yes, there is an method for working with Javascript, observe my revised answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention it's a headless server where I need to implement the solution. However your answer is correct the least is that I confirm that.